# Openshift/Kubernetes ssh Secret doesn't work with Camel SFTP component

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, apache-camel, openshift

Long story short    --->

While passing an ssh-key, which is retrieved from a secret in Openshift to apache-camel SFTP component its not able to connect the server; whereas if I directly pass a path of the actual ssh-key file w/o creating secret to the same component, it works just fine. The exception is, invalid key. I tried to read the key file in java and pass it as ByteArray as a privateKey parameter but no luck. Seems like passing the key as byte is not working as all possible means.

***SFTP-COMPONENT Properties***->

```
sftp:

host: my.sftp.server

port: 22

fileDirectory: /to

fileName: /app/home/file.txt

username: sftp-user

privateKeyFilePath: /var/run/secret/secret-volume/ssh-privatekey **(Also tried privateKey param with byte array)**

knownHostsFile: resource:classpath:keys/known_hosts

binary: true
```

**Application Detail:**
I am using Openshift 3.11.
Developing Camel-SpringBoot Micro-Integration services configured with fabric8 and spring-cloud-kubernetes plugins for deployment.

**I am creating the secret as,**

oc secrets new-sshauth sshsecret --ssh-privatekey=$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa

I have tried to refer secret with deployment.yml and bootstrap.yml

***Using as env variable with secret-key-ref->***

**deployment.yml**->

```
- name: SSH_SECRET

  valueFrom:

    secretKeyRef:

      name: sshsecret

      key: ssh-privatekey
```

**bootstrap.yml**->

```
spring:

  cloud:

    kubernetes:

      secrets:


        enabled: true

        enableApi: true

        name: sshsecret
```

***Using as mounted volume->***

**deployment.yml**->

```
volumeMounts:

- mountPath: /var/run/secret/secret-volume

  name: secret-volume

volumes:

- name: secret-volume

   secret:

      secretName: sshsecret
```

**bootstrap.yml**->

```
spring:

  cloud:

    kubernetes:

      secrets:

        enabled: true

        paths: /var/run/secret/secret-volume
```

**Note:** Once the service is deployed I can see the mounted volume is attached with the container and can even bash into the POD and go to the same directory and locate the private key, which completely intact.

Any help will be appreciated. Ask me all questions you need to know to solve this.

Comment: The name of the private key file specified in `privateKeyFilePath` is `ssh-privatekey`; in the deployment.yml the secretName filed is `secretName: sshsecret`. What is the name of the file in the mounted volume - `ssh-privatekey` or `sshsecret`?

Comment: The secret name which was created in OCP is sshsecret, however inside secret data, we do have key-value pair, so there the key is ssh-privatekey. Therefore, when you mount the secret to a volume, the secret data gets written to a file and file name is the KEY name as mentioned above. In short the name of the file is ssh-privatekey.

Answer (score 0):

It was a very bad mistake from my side. I was using **privateKeyUri** in camel SFTP component instead of **privateKeyFile**. I didn't rectify this and always changing those SFTP parameters in config-map directly.

By the way, for those trying to implement similar usecase; use the second option which is, mounting the secret into a volume and then refer the volume path inside Camel. Don't use the secret as ENV variable, so you need not enable secret API inside bootstrap.yml.

Thanks anyway, cheers!

Rito